# Bayesian probability, verifying stupid examples

Tags: bayesian, intuition

A [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) on Bayesian inference offers an informal example in which a friend has had a baby, about which I know nothing more, and a (presumably reliable) mutual friend shows me a picture of the newborn.  I want to check that I have formalized the problem correctly.  (I am a computer scientist who uses statistics, not a statistician.)  Many thanks for your patience, either in saying that I understand or in pointing out my misunderstanding.

1. Mutual friend shows me a picture (evidence E) of the newborn boy.  My hypothesis H is that the baby is a boy.
   $$
   \Pr\,(H\mid E) = \frac{\Pr\,(E\mid H) \Pr\,(H)}{\Pr\,(E)} = \frac{(1)(.5 - \epsilon)}{.5} = 1 - 2 \epsilon
   $$
   In other words, I may harbour the tiniest suspicion epsilon that mutual friend is wrong or playing a joke, but otherwise, I leave the conversation accepting that the baby is a boy.
2. Mutual friend shows me a picture (evidence E) of the newborn dog.  My hypothesis H is that the baby is a dog.
   $$
   \Pr\,(H\mid E) = \frac{\Pr\,(E\mid H) \Pr\,(H)}{\Pr\,(E)} = \frac{(1)(0)}{\epsilon} = 0
   $$
   In other words, I believe a priori that the hypothesis is clearly false (humans don't give birth to dogs), so the posterior probability of H must be 0.  I assign $\Pr\,(E)$ a positive value in part because maybe mutual friend is naive or confused but mostly because I don't want to divide by zero.  Perhaps I could motivate that last better.

Comment: In your first scenario, how do you understand the symbol $\text {Pr}(E)$? What does "unconditional probability of Evidence" means, as you understand it? (that led you to assign to it a value of $0.5$)?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.  In great part, it's from working backwards -- if the numerator is correct, the denominator must surely about the same.  In part, my rational was that I expect mutual friend to say boy or girl with about equal probability.

Comment: So it appears that "E" (the _evidence itself_) is _not_ "the picture shown to you", but "a statement made by another person about the sex of the newborn". In such a case $\text{Pr}(E)$ appears to be "probability that the statement is correct". but then, you should also specify whether the statement says "it's a boy" or "it's a girl" (in case the probabilities that "the statement is true" are 50-50, it won't matter numerically, but it is the consistent way to go). CONTD

Comment: CONTD But your second scenario sends us somewhere else : it appears you are thinking "assess the correctness of the friend's statement _in light_ of what we see in the picture" - which is a conditional probability on its own.

Comment: Maybe I described the problem poorly.  I was thinking of the statement and the photo as the same.  That is, I don't expect mutual friend to present a photo inconsistent with his statement.

Comment: That is, mutual friend says (and presents a picture) "the baby is a dog".  So I consider the hypothesis "the baby is a dog".